# How to do SQL from Akka?

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, akka, akka-http

What is the idiomatic Akka way to issue SQL statements from an Akka application?

Specifically, I have an Akka Http REST endpoint that wants to do SQL commands. Is there some official SQL support or async or message passing style SQL library?

Comment: A common stack is Akka Http + Slick, a functional-relational mapper which offers a reactive interface over JDBC.

Comment: Slick is a full complex FRM system. I'd prefer to just get simple SQL

Comment: scalikejdbc is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your specific question, "what is the idiomatic akka way to issue sql", I would agree with the commentators that Slick is the usual choice.

Further, I disagree that slick is only a "full complex frm system".  You can always use the [plain sql queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html) functionality within slick.  And slick comes with [streaming](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/dbio.html#streaming) which is obviously "idiomatic" with akka-stream:

> elements are streamed directly from the result set through a Reactive
>   Streams Publisher, which can be processed and consumed by Akka
>   Streams.

Comment: Slick does allow simple SQL and has full Akka streaming integration. That's what I need. Thank you.